# The callback which is called everytime Navigator.push to next page

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two Pages moving each others like this.

`MyHomePage -> ResPage -> MyHomePage -> ResPage`

I want to  exec the function when every time the ResPage appears.

code is this

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ResPage()));

Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MyHomePage())
```

resPage is Stateful Widget.

```
class ResPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ResPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ResPageState createState() => _ResPageState();
}

class _ResPageState extends State<ResPage> {
    void initState(){ // it called just once.
    }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Stack( // it called many times.
        children: <Widget>[
          background,
          Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: resStack
          ),
        ],
      );  
  }
```

`initState()` is called one time, and `build` is called many times.

Is there any call back when the page appears??

Comment: With the scenario, you gave, `initState` should be called at least twice

Comment: I agree with @RemiRousselet init function should be called each time when it the widget is freshly pushed into the stack.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is!

You can add a post frame callback(a call after the widget was built)

like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  WidgetsBinding.addPostFrameCallback(functionToCall);
}
```

Comment: That's a very bad practice. If it was alright to do, Flutter would expose a "postBuild" method on widgets

Comment: I don't think so. That would be a bad practice If you put heavy work or non async work in there. Also that is the problem, Flutter gives you a initState call a build call, but is missing a finish callback that may be needed in some cases!